# How can I view log file more then 1GB

Tags: linux

I have a Linux server with 512MB RAM and no SWAP.
How can I view 1GB file?

Comment: What do you actually want to view here? You have all kinds of options. more, less, tail, grep, cat, ee, vi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use split.**

Another useful tool in addition to head and tail is [split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split).

Chop that 1GB file into a bunch of smaller files.

Answer (score 3):

I think "less" or "more" will work just fine here.
Or you can use below Perl script to do this, just change the log file name:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open LOGFILE, "<log_file" or die "log_file: $!";
my $i=0;
while(<LOGFILE>) {
 if($i>=25) {
  $i=0;
  print "Press Enter to see more...";
  <>;
 }
 else {
  print;
  $i++;
 }
}
close LOG_FILE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Emacs, vim can do it if you need to modify the file. Otherwise, "less" can do it.

Most "good" editors won't load the full file in memory.

Comment: vi: memory exhausted

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd take the process that created the log, stop it, rename the log, touch the old filename to create a new log, then restart the process.

Move the log file to another machine so I can analyze it, store it, whatever needs to be done.

On that machine, I'd use the [Linux Split command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm) to break the file into smaller, more manageable chunks.

Get the information I need from it, then delete it when done.

Your server might thank you for more space. You might want to look at configuring [logrotate](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_logrota.htm) for that logfile on the server itself to help with space management. Chances are pretty good you already have it on the server.

Make sure you don't play with the logfile while the parent process is still running or you may get some goofy side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Download the log file to another computer that has more RAM.

You wouldn't want huge logs on a production server anyway.

Look into logrotate if it is not configured yet.

Answer (score 0):

This Linux without perl. Download log file to another PC is not solution. I resolve this problem by "head" and "tail".